# Post data from Matlab to Pachube (Cosm) using Java Methods

Tags: java, matlab, post, cosm

I am using [JPachube.jar](http://code.google.com/p/jpachube/downloads/list) and Matlab in order to send data to my datastream. This java code works on my machine:

```
package smartclassroom;
import Pachube.Data;
import Pachube.Feed;
//import Pachube.FeedFactory;
import Pachube.Pachube;
import Pachube.PachubeException;

public class SendFeed {     

    public static void main(String arsg[]) throws InterruptedException{
        SendFeed s = new SendFeed(0.0);
        s.setZainteresovanost(0.3);
        double output = s.getZainteresovanost();      
        System.out.println("zainteresovanost " + output);             

        try {
                Pachube p = new Pachube("MYAPIKEY");
                Feed f = p.getFeed(MYFEED);
                f.updateDatastream(0, output);
            } catch (PachubeException e) {
                System.out.println(e.errorMessage);
            }
    }

    private double zainteresovanost;    
    public SendFeed(double vrednost) {
        zainteresovanost = vrednost;
    }
    public void setZainteresovanost(double vrednost) {
        zainteresovanost = vrednost;
    }
    public double getZainteresovanost() {
        return zainteresovanost;
    }

}
```

but I need to do this from Matlab. I have tried rewriting [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056140/530813) (example from link is working on my machine): I have compile java class with javac and added JPachube.jar and SendFeed.class into path and then utilize this code in Matlab:

```
javaaddpath('C:\work')
javaMethod('main','SendFeed','');    
pachubeValue = SendFeed(0.42);
```

I get an error:

```
??? Error using ==> javaMethod
No class SendFeed can be located on Java class path

Error in ==> post_to_pachube2 at 6
javaMethod('main','SendFeed','');
```

This is strange because, as I said example from the link is working.

Afterwards, I decided to include JPachube directly in Matlab code and to write equivalent code in Matlab:

```
 javaaddpath('c:\work\JPachube.jar')

import Pachube.Data.*
import Pachube.Feed.*
import Pachube.Pachube.*
import Pachube.PachubeException.*

pachube = Pachube.Pachube('MYAPIKEY');
feed = pachube.getFeed(MYFEED);
feed.updateDatastream(0, 0.54);
```

And I get this error:

```
??? No method 'updateDatastream' with matching signature found for class 'Pachube.Feed'.

Error in ==> post_to_pachube2 at 12
feed.updateDatastream(0, 0.54);
```

So I have tried almost everything and nothing! Any method making this work will be fine for me. Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This done trick for me (answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064979/how-to-send-data-from-matlab-to-rails))

```
javaaddpath('c:\work\httpcore-4.2.2.jar');
javaaddpath('c:\work\httpclient-4.2.3.jar');


import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity


httpclient = DefaultHttpClient();

httppost = HttpPost('http://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/FEEDID/datastreams/0.csv?_method=put');
httppost.addHeader('Content-Type','text/plain');
httppost.addHeader('X-ApiKey','APIKEY');

params = StringEntity('0.7');
httppost.setEntity(params);

response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: this is certainly a good solution, although you need to fetch the jars, while `urlread2` uses already available `sun.net.www.protocol.http` and `sun.net.www.protocol.https`. I guess  if it's just a single API end-point that your are going to use, then you can take some bits of code from `urlread2` and make put it in a function, therefore making your code pretty much dependency-free. I am not too sure whether Apache HTTP client is better then the Sun's one, any ideas?

Comment: This solution is straightforward. I have tried numerous time to use urlread2 for POST-ing data with different headers without success. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use built-in methods. Matlab has[`urlread`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html)/[`urlwrite`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/urlwrite.html), which could work if all you wish to do is request some CSV data from Cosm API. If you do need to use JSON, it can be handled in [Matlab via a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663061/how-to-use-restful-webservices-in-matlab).

Passissing the Cosm API key, that can be done via `key` parameter like so:

```
cosm_feed_url = "https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/61916.csv?key=<API_KEY>"
cosm_feed_csv = urlread(cosm_feed_url)
```

However, the standard library methods `urlread`/`urlwrite` are [rather limited](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/expanding-urlreads-capabilities/). In fact, the `urlwrite` function is only designed for file input, and I cannot even see any official example of how one could use a formatted string instead. Creating a temporary file would reasonable, unless it's only a few lines of CSV.
You will probably need to use [`urlread2`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2) for anything more serious.

*UPDATE: it appears that `urlread2` [can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14471241/717998).*

Comment: I wish I could extend the example, but unfortunately I don't have Matlab at hand.

Comment: I have found that urlread by default use hardcoded content type. I need to send POST using urlead with content type text/plain; charset=utf-8 and to add api key to header.