# Connecting Neo4j and Matlab

Tags: matlab, neo4j, graph-databases

Would anyone happen to know, if there is any good way of operating Neo4j (or any other graph database) from Matlab?

R environment seems to have RNeo4j and I'm surprised that I didn't find any equivalent.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be happy with just the transactional Cypher endpoint for returning Cypher query results in a table of some sort?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine...

Answer (score 1):

Just few ideas:

- You can use the Cypher REST interface of Neo4J and this [Matlab JSON plugin](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20565-json-parser) (found by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663061/how-to-use-restful-webservices-in-matlab))
- Or you can use the the [Matlab JDBC connection](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/database/ug/sqlite-jdbc-windows.html)  (like SQLite use `OTHER` as vendor string) and the [Neo4J JDBC driver](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc)

Matlba offers also an ODBC Native connection system but unfortunately Neo4J doesn't - even if [there are some experiments](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/5wySTer-GMM/U0fOtuoiQ6IJ) going on...